# How get global keybord in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, x11, shortcut

I have a input method(fcitx) in linux, the switch shortcut is Ctrl+Space. my goal is response something when user switch input method, so i want to grab shortcut of Ctrl+Space.

I try:

1 use XGrabKey, not work when try grab Ctrl+Space(however, it can grab other shortcur)

2 try read /dev/input/event*, the question is, i can hardly know which event is keyboard

Is there any way to solve this problem？

Comment: You can't grab it because grabbed events are only reported to the grabbing client. If you see the event, the input method doesn't, and vice versa. Reading `/dev/input/event/*` is an entirely different level of abstraction and is not appropriate for an X11 client (won't work over the network, with an on-screen keyboard, or in other situations). Furthermore, shortcuts are normally user-selectable and you cannot guarantee it will really be Ctrl+Space. Perhaps you should reformulate your goal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, first i disable Ctrl+Space shorcut of input method, and i can grab it by use XGrabKey.